# How to tunnel TCP traffic over ssh from a docker container?

Tags: docker, aws-lambda, ssh-tunnel, tunnel

**Here is my situation:**
I have an application running locally at home in a docker container, based on lambci/lambda:build-nodejs8.10. The application sends https requests to a remote server on two urls. The remote server, however, only accepts requests from IPs coming from my office network. I can use VPN to connect to the office network but it's not configured to give me a route onto the internet only accessing machines on the network. What I can do is ssh into machines on the office network, which do have internet access.

**Attempts at solution and previous solution:**
Before I've only had to send requests to one URL, say remote1.com. I've solved this by forwarding ports over ssh, like so:

1. Connect to VPN on my local machine
2. Start the docker container in interactive mode with a bash shell
3. redirect traffic for remote1.com to localhost:

   `echo "127.0.0.1 remote1.com" >> /etc/hosts`
4. forward traffic to 127.0.0.1:443 to office.machine.com over ssh:

   `ssh user@office.machine.com -L 443:remote1.com:443`
5. Connect to the docker container from a new terminal and start the application.

This works very well for just one remote url. Trying do step 2-4 twice won't work as the port is already forwarded.

I've tried running sshuttle on the docker-container. Installing it works fine (through cloning the git repo):

```
git clone https://github.com/sshuttle/sshuttle.git
cd sshuttle
sudo ./setup.py install
```

but running it results in the following error:

```
iptables v1.4.18: can't initialize iptables table `nat': Permission denied (you must be root)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
firewall manager: undoing changes.
firewall manager: undoing IPv4 changes.
iptables v1.4.18: can't initialize iptables table `nat': Permission denied (you must be root)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
firewall manager: Error trying to undo IPv4 firewall.
firewall manager: ---> Traceback (most recent call last):
firewall manager: --->   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sshuttle-0.78.5.dev10+g561b648-py2.7.egg/sshuttle/firewall.py", line 270, in main
firewall manager: --->     method.restore_firewall(port_v4, socket.AF_INET, udp, user)
firewall manager: --->   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sshuttle-0.78.5.dev10+g561b648-py2.7.egg/sshuttle/methods/nat.py", line 99, in restore_firewall
firewall manager: --->     if ipt_chain_exists(family, table, chain):
firewall manager: --->   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sshuttle-0.78.5.dev10+g561b648-py2.7.egg/sshuttle/linux.py", line 33, in ipt_chain_exists
firewall manager: --->     raise Fatal('%r returned %d' % (argv, rv))
firewall manager: ---> Fatal: ['iptables', '-t', 'nat', '-nL'] returned 3
firewall manager: undoing /etc/hosts changes.
firewall manager: Error trying to undo /etc/hosts changes.
firewall manager: ---> Traceback (most recent call last):
firewall manager: --->   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sshuttle-0.78.5.dev10+g561b648-py2.7.egg/sshuttle/firewall.py", line 282, in main
firewall manager: --->     restore_etc_hosts(port_v6 or port_v4)
firewall manager: --->   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sshuttle-0.78.5.dev10+g561b648-py2.7.egg/sshuttle/firewall.py", line 51, in restore_etc_hosts
firewall manager: --->     rewrite_etc_hosts({}, port)
firewall manager: --->   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sshuttle-0.78.5.dev10+g561b648-py2.7.egg/sshuttle/firewall.py", line 30, in rewrite_etc_hosts
firewall manager: --->     os.link(HOSTSFILE, BAKFILE)
firewall manager: ---> OSError: [Errno 18] Invalid cross-device link
fatal: ['iptables', '-t', 'nat', '-nL'] returned 3
c : fatal: cleanup: ['/usr/bin/python', '/usr/local/bin/sshuttle', '-v', '-v', '--method', 'auto', '--firewall'] returned 99
 s:   Ready: 1 r=[4] w=[] x=[]
```

**What I can and cannot do:**

Can:

- Install software and change configurations on my local PC (Win/Ubuntu)
- Install software on the docker-image (not all packages are available by default though)

Cannot:

- Change configuration or install software on the remote or office server

Is there a way of running all (or all HTTPS request to the two specific urls) TCP traffic from the application running in the docker container through the office computer over ssh?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [proxychains](https://github.com/haad/proxychains) can help you.

First, change you ssh command to open a socks proxy at port 9050:

`ssh user@office.machine.com -D 9050`

Then configure your docker image to start node like this:

`proxychains node --node_parameters`

This will cause all requests being made from the node application to pass through the socks proxy located at localhost:9050.